# Ring properties of $\mathbb Z_{(p)}\subset\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I stumbled across the example $$\mathbb Z_{(p)}=\{\frac{a}{b}\mid p\nmid b\text{ and }\gcd(a,b)=1\}$$ for a localization of a ring and don't find it trivial to see that this indeed is a subring of $\mathbb Q$. How does one show the properties mathematically rigorous? If I take $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$, then surely $p\nmid bd$ and also I can "cancel" the fraction $\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$ to a point where I get a coprime denominator and numerator. The same goes for $\frac{ac}{bd}$. But that doesn't sound rigorous to me.

Comment: Formally speaking, $a/b$ is the equivalence class of a pair $(a,b)$ of integers, and
$$(a,b) \sim (c,d) \iff ad-bc=0.$$
Then $\Bbb Q$ is defined by taking the equivalence class of _all_ pairs $(a,b)$ of integers, with $b \neq 0$. Then $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ is defined by taking the equivalence class of _all_ pairs $(a,b)$ of integers, where $p \nmid b$.

Answer (score 1):

Just prove the required properties.

First, show that $0\in\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ and $1\in\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. Indeed 
$$0=\frac{0}{1}
\qquad
0=\frac{1}{1}
$$
and $p\nmid 1$.

Now, suppose $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. By definition, we can write $x=a/b$ and $y=c/d$ with $p\nmid b$ and $p\nmid d$. Then
$$
x-y=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad-bc}{bd}
\qquad
xy=\frac{a}{b}\,\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ac}{bd}
$$
which belong to $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ because $p\nmid bd$.

No need to “reduce” fractions.

---

An important point. Suppose $p=3$ just by way of example. Then
$$
x=\frac{9}{6}\in\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}
$$
notwithstanding $3\mid 6$, because we *can* express
$$
x=\frac{3}{2}
$$
and $2\nmid 3$.

In the arguments above I just assume $x=a/b$ *with* $p\nmid b$, because this is possible by definition of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

You're probably mystified by the definition you've been given. The added condition $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is completely useless and can happily be removed. Defining
$$
\mathbb Z_{(p)}=\left\{\frac{a}{b}: p\nmid b\right\}
$$
would be exactly the same, because if $p\nmid b$, then also $p\nmid b'$ and
$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a'}{b'}
$$
where $d=\gcd(a,b)$, $a=da'$ and $b=db'$. This frees you from “simplifying fractions”.

Comment: But in the definition I gave the fraction is always reduced which isn't the case for your x and y. That is basically my question.

Comment: @Buh So what? Does $3/2\in\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$? Yes, even if you write the fraction as $9/6$.

Comment: I would say $9/6\notin\mathbb Z_{(3)}$ but $3/2$ is. These elements are different although being in the same coset in $\mathbb Q$. Again: That was my question - how do I argue properly here?

Comment: I wouldn’t say that, @Buh. $9/6$ and $3/2$ aren’t “in the same coset in $\Bbb Q$”, rather they are representations of the same single element of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Buh I added some comments about the issue you seem to have.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\mathbb Q$ can be seen as the localization of $\Bbb Z$ at the prime ideal $(0)$.
By universal property of localization, there exists one and only one ring homomorphism $\varphi:\Bbb Z_{(p)}\to\Bbb Q$ making the following diagram commutative:

[image]

This ring homomorphism is, in fact, injective, hence $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ can be identified with a subring of $\Bbb Q$, namely the image of $\varphi$:
$$\operatorname{Im}\varphi=\left\{\frac ab\in\Bbb Q:p\nmid b\right\}$$
Note that your requirement $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - my problem here though is more elementary.